# Not Logging On In Codeigniter With Custom Validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my codeigniter login I am not having any no luck logging on. I throws One error now called. `Undefined property: error message`. I also am not sure if my **validate** is correct if that is why not picking up **user**.

**Error**

`Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysqli_driver::$num_rows`

**Library File**

```
public function login() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('session');
        $this->CI->load->library('security/encryption');


        $password = $this->CI->input->post('password');
        $username = $this->CI->input->post('username');

        $user_query = $this->CI->db->select('*')
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->where('password',  $this->CI->encryption->hash_password().hash('sha512', $password).$this->CI->encryption->generate_salt())
        ->where('status', "1")
        ->from('user');
        if($user_query->num_rows) {

              $data = array(
                    'ip' => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
                    'user_id' => $this->CI->session->userdata('user_id')
              );

              $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
              $this->db->update('user', $data); 

              return true;

        } else {

              return false;

        }
  }
```

I use my own form validation method rather than codeigniter way. My way I have more control over it.

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
            $this->load->library('users');
            $this->lang->load('common/login', 'english')


            if(($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {

                  $data = array(
                      'username' => $this->input->post(),
                      'user_id' => $row->user_id,
                      'isLogged' => true
                  );
                  $this->db->get('user');
                  $this->session->set_userdata($data);

                  redirect('dashboard');
            }

            if (array_key_exists('warning', $this->error)) {
                  $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
            } else {
                  $data['error_warning'] = '';
            }

            if (array_key_exists('username', $this->error)) {
                  $data['error_username'] = $this->error['username'];
            } else {
                  $data['error_username'] = '';
            }

            if (array_key_exists('password', $this->error)) {
                  $data['error_password'] = $this->error['password'];
            } else {
                  $data['error_password'] = '';
            } 

            $data['action'] = site_url("login");

            if (!"" == trim($this->input->post('username'))) {
                  $data['username'] = $this->input->post('username');
            } else {
                  $data['username'] = '';
            }

            if (!"" == trim($this->input->post('password'))) {
                  $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
            } else {
                  $data['password'] = '';
            }

            $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);
      }

      protected function validate() {
            if (!"" == trim($this->input->post('username')) || !"" == trim($this->input->post('password')) || !$this->users->login($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password'))) {
                  $this->error['warning'] = $this->lang->line('error_login');
            }

            return !$this->error;
      }
}
```

Comment: Just add ->get() to your $this->CI->db to use num_rows()

Comment: No more errors but still not letting me login though even though database is correct

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in oop or in CodeIgniter but your library doesn't make much sense to me.

Try doing `var_dump()` of  your `$user_query->num_rows`, also the query looks like it's using CI active record so the query should look something like this

```
// build the query
$this->CI->db->select('*');
$this->CI->db->from('user');
$this->CI->db->where('username', $username);
$this->CI->db->where('password',  $this->CI->encryption->hash_password().hash('sha512', $password).$this->CI->encryption->generate_salt());
$this->CI->db->where('status', "1");

// execute query
$query = $this->CI->db->get();

// do your thing
if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {

    $data_row = $query->row();

    $data = array(
            'ip' => $this->CI->input->ip_address(),
            'user_id' => $data_row->user_id // you don't have user_id in session
        );

    $this->db->where('user_id', $data_row->user_id); // same thing here for user_id
    $this->db->update('user', $data); 

    // You should start session here because you want to login the user :)

    return true;
}
```

I think this should do the trick. Also you were using `user_id` from session that doesn't exists. You are in process of loging in so you can't have `user_id` in it. This way we use result of query for it.
You should consider of starting session if result is true and store some data in it.